# How to plot many lines on a line plot using ggplot and have them as distinct different colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that has 3 numerical values

```
T
kWh
Month
```

The `T` variable holds values between 1 and 48 and the `kWh` variable is discrete.

I'm trying to display a line graph that shows the average `kWh` at each `T` for every `Month` by having an individual line for each `Month` (average `kWh` on the Y axis and `T` on the X axis.)

My approach was the following

```
grouped_by_t = group_by(df, T)
summarised_by_t = summarise(grouped_by_t, Average=mean(kWh, na.rm=TRUE), Month=Month)
```

And finally plotting it like so

```
ggplot(data=summarised_by_t, aes(x=T, y=Average, group=Month, color=Month)) + geom_line()
```

Unfortunately, this just displayed one line with a colour gradient at the edge of the plot which isn't what I want.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Since you want the average "at each `T` for every `Month`", I think you would want to group by both ` T` and `Month` instead of just `T`.  The size of your summary data frame be close to 576 rows (assuming that you have a value for distinct combination of `T` and `Month` and that only 12 months are being used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a sample of your dataset, `df`, I've generated complete nonsense data that at least should be able to give a plot along the lines of what you are looking to accomplish.

Although it can definitely be done by summarizing your dataset beforehand, you can also utilize `stat_summary()` to do the averaging for you based on setting the aesthetic for `color`.  In this case, `stat_summary()` will use that aesthetic as the grouping aesthetic for computing the mean.

Here's the code to generate my horrible dataset and the plot code.  Note as well I included setting the levels of `df$Month` before plotting, otherwise `ggplot2` will default to representing the months in alphabetical order.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  Month=rep(month.name, each=200),
  T=sample(1:48, 2400, replace=TRUE),
  kWh=rnorm(2400, 500, 140))

df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels=month.name)

ggplot(df, aes(x=T, y=kWh, color=Month)) +
  stat_summary(geom='line', fun=mean)
```

[image]

For just a bit more context in case you were unaware, the function set for `fun=` value returns a value that is used for the `y` aesthetic.  In plain text, the `stat_summary()` function here is set to draw a `geom_line` represented as the `mean` value of `df$kWh` for each `df$T`, separated by color for each `df$Month`.